# tailwindcss flex cols with different height position

Tags: tailwind-css

I am trying to achieve a positioning ala Pinterest.

When adding a row it fills the space from left to right then goes on the next line.

I am able to do it with same element height.
But I am unable to get it working for different heights.

What I want it the 3rd design in my screenshot.

[image]

Do you have an idea?

Thanks

Here is my attempt https://play.tailwindcss.com/iIzk4Z32Q3

Comment: This sound like a job for grid. You make a grid of 2 cols, each col has 3 rows. First column has green, white, red. second col has red, red, white

Comment: @dasfacc The issue with doing a 2 column grid layout in this instance is that the poster is looking for a feed style layout. This will cause items to be out of order or very difficult to automate or maintain. The poster needs a masonry grid.

Comment: @thierryb it seems there is still no straightforward way to do this with CSS yet. Soon (I hope) CSS Grid level 3 spec will be adopted by all browsers and the masonry layout will be a native and simple thing to implement but for now you will most likely need some Javascript to accomplish the ordering https://www.smashingmagazine.com/native-css-masonry-layout-css-grid/

Answer (score 0):

A bit hard to understand what you're trying to achieve but if you just want the blue bar to sit under the green bar, then you just need to wrap them in a parent div. Try this:

```html
<div class="flex flex-row flex-wrap items-start">
  <div class="w-1/2">
    <div class="bg-green-500">
      <div class="h-4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-blue-500">
      <div class="h-4"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-1/2 bg-red-500">
    <div class="h-12"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```